# Where should resource DLL be loaded by LoadLibrary() API in MFC application?

Tags: mfc

I have some static string objects in MFC class, in MFC application. I want these strings objects to be populated from string resources which are kept in separate MFC dll. The problem is : As string objects are static members, initialization code is executed before even I load resource dll within `CMyApp::InitInstance()` method?

How this situation should be handled? Where should I call `::LoadLibrary()` API to load resource dll? or any other workaround?

Comment: You don't have to do anything; MFC already does this for you. See [Localized Resources in MFC Applications: Satellite DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/localized-resources-in-mfc-applications-satellite-dlls).

Comment: What if application is not using satellite dll? Lets say app is not using localization, just using mfc resource dll containing different resources and loaded at run-time from App's InitInstance() method?

Comment: Is there any reason why the strings need to be static? You could just have a reference to an object which holds the strings and initialize this from the DLL string resources in `CYourApp::InitInstance()`.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely one way. But if due to some constraints, string should be kept static member variable, then any other way?

Comment: Change your static member variables to static accessors. Have a local static variable in each accessor store the value and simply return it. Statics are initialized on first use starting with C++11.